# Cross component communication in angular

Tags: angular, components

I have three component in my app. First `header` component, second `sideNavBar` component and third one, `overview` component. 
i am showing that with, 1,2,3 in below pic.

[image]

when i choose any social platform , i am sending user to `home/overview` and i want that, in my `sideNavBar` , related icon's color change.

method i am using when user click on each social on header is here:

```
onActiveSocial(social) {
    localStorage.setItem('activeAccountMedium', social);
    this.appGlobal.activeSocial = social;
    this.router.navigate(['home/overview']);
  }
```

i know i must write some trigger in this method to make icon in `sideNavBar` change color.

i must say these 3 component unrelated to each other.

how can i do this ?

Comment: You using `localStorage` for saving current tab, is that right?

Comment: You can use `routerLinkActive`. https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

Comment: @SangwinGawande yes i use localStorage to know every moment which social platform is active.

Comment: have you tried SharedService for this?

Comment: @SangwinGawande yes but i think i did it wrong , cuz it did not work

Comment: @Mohandes create service and observer function

Comment: @Abhishek how can i do this exactly ?

Comment: @Mohandes not exactly this but similar to this. if you understand how give data from component to service  and how to get data from it in other component.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53760569/angular-pass-data-from-material-dialog-to-component-which-didnt-open-the-dial/53766214#53766214)

Comment: @ShashankVivek it is good but problem is i want to make one icon blue and other icon in my last rout that was blue get purple now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1: (if the color you want to apply on sidenav has nothing to do with the active route)
Services are designed for same, (Dependency Injection)

```
export class SomeService {
private color: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('Green');
get _color() {
  return this.color.asObservable();
}
constructor() {}

public updateColor(val) {
 this.color.next(val);
 }
}
```

Provide this service in the parent module or root module of the components (app.module.ts)

inject the service in components

```
    overview.component.ts
    constructor(private someService: SomeService) {

    }
    // update the variable here on some method
    this.someService.updateColor('red');

    sidenav.component.ts
    color: string;
    constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}
    ngOnInIt() {
      this.someService._color.subscribe((val) => {
         this.color= val;
      });
    }
   ngOnDestroy() {
   //unsubscribe on destroye
  }
```

To be honest its overKilling for such a problem simply use routerLinkActive it will be easier

2.Solution 2:
You can use routerLinkActive property provided by angular to apply a class when the route is active refer 
https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive
for more

Comment: how can i use get and set method to update my side nav component. when my main app comes up , side nav and header , get execute. when i click on social button on header my sidenav component dose not execute again so nothing don't get updated