# To send JSON data from dialog component to other component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I have 2 components called `list` and `details` which are placed inside an component called `customer`.
On clicking the `delete` button in `details` component an dialog window will be opened like this:

[image]

On clicking `delete` button in dialog window, I am emitting an function called **onDelete** along with  `JSON` values so that i can re use that 
 function(onDelete) in other component.

**HTML**

```
 <p>Do you want to delete <span>{{data?.title}} ?</span></p>
   <br>
  <button (click)="onDelCustomer()">DELETE</button>
```

**TS**

```
 import { Component, Input , OnInit, Output, Inject, EventEmitter } from 
  '@angular/core';
 import {
    FormBuilder,
    FormControl,
    FormGroup,
    Validators,
   } from '@angular/forms';
   import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-delete',
      templateUrl: './delete.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./delete.component.css']
     })
    export class DeleteComponent {
      @Input()
      public contact;

     @Output() public onDelete: EventEmitter<{}> = new EventEmitter();

     constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
        private fb: FormBuilder,) { }


      public onDelCustomer(): void {
       this.onDelete.emit(this.data); <==========
       console.log(this.data)
      }


    }
```

When i `log` those emitted JSON values in `delete` component, I am able to see JSON values like this:

[image]

But when log the same emitted values in `customer` component i am unable to see, I am calling the emitted function like this:

```
  public onDelete() {
    this.someContact = this.data; <========
    console.log(this.someContact);
  }
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-rvbyr5?file=app/customer/customer.component.ts)**

> Updated code

Previously i was performing **delete** operation in `delete` component itself like this:

```
  public onDelCustomer(): void { <============== code for deleting customer
    this.someContact = this.data;
    this.someContact.id = this.data.id;
    this.customersServiceList.deleteContact('00000000-11111-1111-0000000', 
    this.someContact, this.someContact.id);
  }
```

But i want perform `delete` operation in `customer` component like this:

```
   public onDelete() {
    this.someContact = this.data;
    this.someContact.id = this.data.id;
    this.customersServiceList.deleteContact('00000000-11111-1111-0000000', 
     this.someContact, this.someContact.id);
  }
```

Because i want to make `delete`component  as an **generic component** so that i can reuse it, So i want perform `delete` operation in customer.

Comment: are you using material ?

Comment: @Shankarguru look at this example i think it will be help you (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53760569/angular-pass-data-from-material-dialog-to-component-which-didnt-open-the-dial/53766214#53766214) in this example i have take data from from and share with other component

Comment: Ya i am using `material`, but what is the connection between `material` and my `issue`?

Comment: m= i ahve dlted my answer.. thanks for wasting my time

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe your onDelete output event in customer.component.ts.
As the event is emitted only when delete is clicked and then call your customer component's delete function inside subscribe.

You can do like this:

```
  public openDialogDelete($event: any): void {
    const dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DeleteComponent> = this.dialog.open(
      DeleteComponent,
      {
        width: "350px",
        data: $event
      }
    );
       // add these lines
    dialogRef.componentInstance.onDelete.subscribe(data => {
      console.log("deleted data--", data);
       // edit
       this.onDelete();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance you lost your data scope, because your delete modal is `*ngIf`-ed and deleted when button get's clicked. So, basically component dies (it's removed from DOM), all it's `this` are undefined while you are try to refer to this data from other component via event emitter. Consider to use common service to traverse this delete message across components:

Provide common subject in service, emit to this subject in delete modal and subscribe to it in customer component.