# To send data from dialog component to other components in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an component called `delete` which i am displaying in the dialog window. For this component i am `injecting` data like this:

**delete.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input , OnInit, Output, Inject, EventEmitter } from 
  '@angular/core';
import {
    FormBuilder,
    FormControl,
    FormGroup,
    Validators,
 } from '@angular/forms';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-delete',
  templateUrl: './delete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./delete.component.css']
 })

export class DeleteComponent {
@Input()
public contact;

constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
        private fb:FormBuilder,) {} <=== Injecting data to component

 public ondelCustomer(): void {  <======== DELETE Function
   this.someContact = this.data;
   this.someContact.id = this.data.id;
   this.customersService.deleteContact('00000000-11111-1111-0000000', 
   this.someContact, this.someContact.id);
  }


 }
```

**delete.compoent.html**

```
  <p>Do you want to delete <span>{{data?.name}}?</span></p>

  <button  (click)="onDelCustomer()">DELETE</button>
```

The template UI looks like this:

[image]

As shown in the code on clicking **DELETE** button in template(delete.component.html) will  call `onDelCustomer()` function. Which will perform `delete` operation like this:

```
  public ondelCustomer(): void {
   this.someContact = this.data;
   this.someContact.id = this.data.id;
   this.customersService.deleteContact('00000000-11111-1111-0000000', 
   this.someContact, this.someContact.id);
  }
```

Now the issue is i don't want call this `ondelCustomer()` function in `delete` component, I want call this `ondelCustomer()` function in other components, So that i can reuse this `delete` component.

So i tried like this:

```
 **HTML**

 <p>Do you want to delete <span>{{data?.name}}?</span></p>

<button (click)="onDelCustomer()">DELETE</button>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, Input , OnInit, Output, Inject, EventEmitter } from 
  '@angular/core';
import {
 FormBuilder,
 FormControl,
 FormGroup,
 Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-delete',
 templateUrl: './delete.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./delete.component.css']
})

export class DeleteComponent {
@Input()
public contact;

@Output() public onDelete: EventEmitter<{}> = new EventEmitter();<========
 constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
        private fb: FormBuilder,) {}


 public onDelCustomer(): void {
  this.onDelete.emit(this.data);<===============
  console.log(this.data)
 }


 }
```

On calling the `onDelCustomer()` I am emitting `onDelete` event as in above code, and i am calling `onDelete`event  in another component(customer component) like this:

**customer.component.ts**

```
  import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
  import { Service } from '../service';
  import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
  import { IContact } from '../models';
  import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MatListOption} from 
  '@angular/material';
  import { DeleteComponent } from '../delete/delete.component';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-customer',
    templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./customer.component.css']
  })

  export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  data;

  contacts:IContact[];
  someContact:IContact[];

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
         public customersServiceList: Service) {}

  public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
   this.contacts  = await this.customersServiceList.getContactList();
  }

  public openDialogDelete($event: any): void { 
    const dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DeleteComponent> = 
    this.dialog.open(DeleteComponent,{ width:'350px',data:$event,});
  }

 public onDelete() {
  this.someContact = this.data;
  console.log(this.someContact);
  this.someContact.id = this.data.id;
  this.customersService.deleteContact('00000000-11111-1111-0000000', 
   this.someContact, this.someContact.id);
 }


 }
```

> When i log in **customer** component i am unable to recive the data from dialog component(i,e delete component).

i am unable guess what's wrong with the code.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-rvbyr5?file=app%2Fcustomer%2Fcustomer.component.ts)**

Comment: check on this link for how to share data material-dilaog to component with the help of service(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53760569/angular-pass-data-from-material-dialog-to-component-which-didnt-open-the-dial/53766214#53766214).

Comment: have you check my example?

Comment: I have checked, but i unable to implement in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Delete Button Click, call this function:

```
onDeleteClick() {
  this.dialog.close({action: 1, data: this.data});
}
```

Here, action and 1 are arbitrary values, can be anything.

Now, in the component from where you have opened the dialog, use this function:

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Service } from '../service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IContact } from '../models';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MatListOption} from '@angular/material';
import { DeleteComponent } from '../delete/delete.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer',
  templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer.component.css']
})
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  data;
 contacts:IContact[];

someContact:IContact[];

 constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
             public customersServiceList: Service) {}



  public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
   this.contacts  = await this.customersServiceList.getContactList();
  }

 public openDialogDelete($event: any): void { 
  this.dialog.open(DeleteComponent, {
    width: '350px',data:$event,
}).afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
  if(data && data.action === 1) {
    this.onDelete(data.data);
  }
});

}

public onDelete(data: any) {
  console.log('called');
this.someContact = data;
console.log(this.someContact);
}


}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, What does `action: 1` means?

Comment: It could be anything, like random: 'test', it is just any key value pair which we use in parent component to verify that delete button click caused the dialog to close, since we only pass this particular data when delete button is clicked. Hope this clears you doubt,

Comment: Always a pleasure. :)